# javaMail send email over MSExchange

Tags: exchange-server, jakarta-mail

I have a web site that send mails using javaMail library, **that works fine until we changed the mail service to MSExchange**.

I recompiled the project setting the new host configuration and testing in my computer and work fine using GlassFish, Then I try it on testing server in glassfish too.
When I deploy the application in producction don't work, the log don't show me any error, there are some diference between dev/testing enviroment and production, first dev and testing is over the network 10.226.xxx.xxx and production 192.168.xxx.xxx and in producction we have a tomcat.

I sended an email in production server using telnet conecting to smtp and works fine.

I realy lost, I don't know how (and what) to fix it...

```
try {
        Byte newMailStatus = 0;
        SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage(this.templateMessage);
        msg.setSubject("Hi!");
        msg.setText("xxx");

        try {
            this.mailSender.send(msg);
            newMailStatus = 1;
        } catch (MailException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
            newMailStatus = 0;
        }


        ALimitResult result = new ALimiteResult();
        result.setStatus(newMailStatus);

        getModel().put("model", result);

        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("EmailView", getModel());

        return modelView;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

(SMTP server authentication is disabled)

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="exchange.mydomain.com" />
        <property name="username" value="email@mydomain.com" />
        <property name="password" value="helpme" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

NEW: In production server I get this error:

2011-09-07 10:30:58,248 ERROR [xxx-myController] - Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client

I made a "ehlo" to get the authentication methods on the SMTP server, I get this:

- 250-svrexch.mydomain.com Hello [192.168.1.10]
- 250-SIZE 10485760
- 250-PIPELINING
- 250-DSN
- 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
- 250-STARTTLS
- 250-AUTH
- 250-8BITMIME
- 250-BINARYMIME
- 250-CHUNKING
- 250-XEXCH50
- 250 XSHADOW